# <ion-img> is truncating the src

Tags: ionic2

I have a simple `ion-img` element:

```
<ion-img *ngIf="images.length" [width]="w" [height]="h" [src]="thumb"></ion-img>
```

**Problem**: Image doesn't show, even if I place hard-coded URL

```
<ion-img *ngIf="images.length"  [width]="w" [height]="h" src="http://img.mako.co.il/2017/04/05/141414_x5.jpg"></ion-img>
```

Inspecting the element shows that the `src` has a truncated string of the thumb URL ( 31 characters exactly for each entire array )

just FYI, if I `console.log("thumb:", thumb)` -> show a valid thumb URL ...

I was able to pin-point the issue, and if I remove the `*ngIf="images.length"` - the image is shown .... but the above was just for the example ( this is how I caught this case ) - the real code is that - I'm waiting for an Array to be filled from an `Http` request ...

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/433y7EIjWBsEzbPkCi7H?p=preview, the code is in `home.ts` & `home.html`, click the button called `Set True` - an and  you'll see a small gray square next to it, remove the `*ngIf="ionimg"` - you'll see the img just fine ....

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you can see [in the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/):

> **Note**: ion-img is only meant to be used inside of virtual-scroll

So if you're not using a virtual-scroll, you'll need to use the standard `img` element or a div and set the image as the background.

Comment: bummer ......... I still don't understand why it doesn't work ... because if it wouldn't have truncated the `src=` everything would be fine

Comment: Yeah, a few versions ago, it still worked even outside of the `virtual-scroll` but then it started to show some bugs/issues and the docs were updated with that information. I'm sorry :(